# CKEditor control not displaying images

Tags: asp.net, ckeditor

Using visual studio 2019, I've installed ckeditor for net v3.6.4 from Nuget, and added it to an aspx page.   The control works fine except that it will not display images.. I've tried pasting images in and by adding them as by URL to no avail.

I've edited the config.js file and added 'Image' to the toolbar and the insert image icon appears and when pressed opens the image dialog.  But even when I use a valid URL to an image file, it does not display in the control, even though pressing the source button shows the correct markup.
I've also just tried pasting an image directly into the control and it does in fact paste the encoded image in, i.e. I can see it in source mode, but again, it does not display.

Sorry it's a bit long, but here's what's in the Source view..

```
<p>
    Before Picture</p>
<p>
    <img alt="" src="data:image/png;base64,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" /></p>
<p>
    After Picture</p>
```

But the control just displays:

Before Picture

After Picture

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured this out.

It was down to a security policy in web.config..

```
        <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';" />
```

I needed to add "data:"  before the semi-colon and then images appeared correctly.

```
        <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data:;" />
```